# Two model to a controller in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have json model called `contact` this is how it looks:

```
{firstName:"",lastName:"",country:""}
```

I have an another model called `country` which contains the list of countries. I want this list of countries in a `dropdown`. While selecting a country from the `dropdown`, country field in contact model should get updated. How can i achieve that?

Comment: can you share what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [named data model](http://vephxinfra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/demokit/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#setModel) and [multimodel support](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f1156f6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

In your controller js,

```
this.getView().setModel(oCountryModel,"Country");
this.getView().setModel(ocontactModel ,"Contact");
```

If you want set Contact model with your default value, add logic in your init function:

```
init:function() {
    //initialize contact model with default country
    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("country",
                      sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ ,"America");

    //suppose  you have a Contact table called ContactList
    var oTable =this.getView().byId("ContactList");
    oTable.getBinding("items").filter([oFilter]);
}
```

In your view xml, use named model data binding, for example:

```
<Text text="{Contact>/firstName}"/>
```

Then you are using two models in your controller and view xml. Regarding dropdown selection change triggers an update for your contact, you need to attach event listener to the dropdown, and update the Contact data model based on the selected country. See the following code:

```
 handleSelectionChange:function(oEvent) {

         //get the new selected country 
        var country =  oEvent.getParameters().newValue;        

        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("country",
                      sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ ,country);

        //suppose  you have a Contact table called ContactList
        var oTable =this.getView().byId("ContactList");
        oTable.getBinding("items").filter([oFilter]);
  }
```

Comment: that will work if we give attachChange event on Dropdown.But country value should be empty if we didnt change the dropdown.After rendering the drop down controller with country values and by default it set to America. Then the value of country in the contact model should be empty.But if we made any change in the dropdown then the selected value should be assigned to the model.The cases like if we didnt change, country in the contact model should set with the default dropdown value.

Comment: I really don't follow. What is your default dropdown value if you didn't change the dropdown, America or Empty? If it is empty, then show all the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

**The simple steps to get this done are:**

```
 1. Set the Contact Model where ever you want such as View or Core.

 2. Set the Country Model to DropDown list.

 3. On selection of the DropDown list, on Change function you set Country field by the value you select in Dropdown list.

 4. This will update the country value in the Contact Model.
```

Comment: This is correct.If i didnt select anything from dropdown then the value in contact model will be empty.How will i set the contact model with default selected country.

Comment: This is not a good idea but you want to set a default country value  why don't you hard code with a value you want to set if you change it will automatic update the Country value.